# svn dump test data?

Tags: svn, repository

I'm working on some analysis tools to look at svn dump files, but I don't have a good test data set. Is there any way to "clone" a public svn repository, so I can create test data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [svnrdump tool](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.c.dump.html) introduced by subversion 1.7 can create dump files from remote repositories.